# Amcl navigation using turtlebot [transformation error ]

Tags: navigation, turtlebot, ros-kinetic, gmapping, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I created a grid map using a turtlebot and after I wanted to navigate in that map I used the navigation stack Amcl but after I run it using the turtlebot navigation package I am getting this errors in transformations could someone tell me what is wrong here ?

I am using ros kinetic and I do have a real turtlebot

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/314462/amcl-navigation-using-turtlebot-%5Btransformation-error-%5D/) by [Jad](https://answers.ros.org/users/35872/jad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2019-02-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-02-01**:
Can you provide your launch files and the amcl configuration please ? (and detail the commands you run)

**Comment by [Jad](https://answers.ros.org/users/35872/jad/) on 2019-02-01**:
It is solved the problem was with the laser scanner. I am converting 3d points cloud to laserscanner and I forget to remap the topic but now it is working well. Thanks

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-02-01**:
Can you answer your own question detailling what you did and mark it has correct ? Since questions related to transformation errors are (very) recurent that could help future people encountering this kind if issue to find your solution more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was using the navigation package for turtlebot. The problem is the package launches all the lasserscanner and the cameras as subscribes automatically. But for me I was using my own laserscanner topic that I got from merging three projected 3D point clouds and it has different name of the standard `/scan` topic. I just remapped my scan topic to `/scan` and it worked.

---

Originally posted by [Jad](https://answers.ros.org/users/35872/jad/) with karma: 75 on 2019-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1